Why is the onDrag closure called after dropping an item in SwiftUI?
I want to implement drag and drop in a LazyVGrid and created the following view (drag'n'drop doesn't work here as I reduced the code example to a minimum in order to focus on the second call of the onDrop closure):
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var items: [ItemModel] = (0..<30).map { .init(position: $0, id: $0) }
    @State var draggedItem: ItemModel?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [.init(.fixed(100)), .init(.fixed(100)), .init(.fixed(100))]) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    print("item", item.id)
                    return ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .foregroundStyle(.mint)
                        Text("\(item.position)")
                            .padding()
                    }
                    .onDrop(of: [.plainText], delegate: ItemDropDelegate())
                    .onDrag {
                        // This is called a second time *after* the drop has completed
                        print("––– onDrag –––", item.id)
                        draggedItem = item
                        return NSItemProvider(object: String(item.id) as NSString)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: draggedItem) { oldValue, newValue in
            print("draggedItem:", newValue!.id)
        }
    }
}

with this simple model type:
struct ItemModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var position: Int
    var id: Int
}

and the most basic DropDelegate one might imagine:
struct ItemDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        print("Drop performed")
        // In my full implementation, 
        // I set the view's draggedItem to nil here through a binding.
        // → Excluded that logic from this example to keep it simple.
        return false
    }
}

I would expect the onDrag closure to be called exactly once when the user initiates the drag gesture on an item. But I've observed by the use of a print statement that it's actually called twice: the second time happens roughly a second after the user has already released the dragged item and dropped it on the grid.
As a result, the draggedItem is assigned an ItemModel value and is not nil despite nothing being dragged anymore.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

(Note: I asked this question before but had missed to share the code for the ItemModel and the ItemDropDelegate which is now included.)

Having the same issue. Tested it and looks like it's a bug on iOS 18. It's working fine on iOS 17

I ended up adding a timestamp and some guard condition as a workaround

What do you guard for? I mean, you never know if the call of the onDrag closure was user-initiated or a result of this apparent bug.

in performDrop or anywhere else I that set draggedItem back to nil, I also set a timestamp, then in onDrag I added guard Date().timeIntervalSince(timestamp) >= 2 else { return NSItemProvider() }. That way it will ignored that bugged onDrag

OK, so you take into account that with a 2 seconds time frame after dropping an item, the user can't initiate another drag operation, right? I guess it's the only thing one can do unless this is fixed in SwiftUI. Thanks for this suggestion!

Exactly, not ideal, but still good enough for me
